# SVG SMIL animation growing element

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate, smil

Can anybody explain me which determines the direction of the "growing" animation? I'll show little example

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Ring" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 450 320" style="enable-background:new 0 0 450 320;" xml:space="preserve">
  
  <path id="innerRing" fill="none"; stroke="#F7DE4B"; stroke-width="10"; stroke-miterlimit="10"; d="M227.1,25.8c-43.4,0-78.6,8.6-78.6,19.4s35.2,19.4,78.6,19.4s78.6-8.6,78.6-19.4
 S270.6,25.8,227.1,25.8z"/>

 <animate xlink:href="#innerRing" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 168.409 0 168.409 " to="0 0 326.818 0" begin="0" dur="1"  repeatCount="1" /> 

 <path id="outerRingMin" fill="none"; stroke="#B2A31B"; stroke-width="0.9"; stroke-miterlimit="10";
 d="M227.1,59.8c-40.5,0-73.2-6.5-73.2-14.5s32.8-14.5,73.2-14.5c40.5,0,73.2,6.5,73.2,14.5
 S267.5,59.8,227.1,59.8"/>

 <animate xlink:href="#outerRingMin" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 153.693 0 153.693" to="0 0 307.386 0" begin="0" dur="1"  repeatCount="1" />
 
 <path id="outerRingMax" fill="none"; stroke="#B2A31B"; stroke-width="0.9"; stroke-miterlimit="10"; d="M227.1,69c46,0,83.4-10.7,83.4-24s-37.3-24-83.4-24c-46,0-83.4,10.7-83.4,24
 c0,13.2,36.7,23.8,82.1,24L227.1,69z"/>

 <animate xlink:href="#outerRingMax" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 181.92 0 181.92" to="0 0 363.84 0" begin="0" dur="1"  repeatCount="1" />

  </svg>
```

Why is the middle circle (yellow) rising from the bottom to up. ? How does it change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because start point of the middle circle is flipped.

The easiest way to fix it is adding stroke-dasshoffset attribute to middle circle to move beginning point of stroke, like this.

```
<path id="innerRing" fill="none" stroke="#F7DE4B" 
stroke-dashoffset="168.409" 
stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
d="M227.1,25.8c-43.4,0-78.6,8.6-78.6,19.4s35.2,19.4,78.6,19.4s78.6-8.6,78.6-19.4
    S270.6,25.8,227.1,25.8z"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I didn't understand why it happened. Why is the start point flipped?

Comment: The start points of path strings(value of d attribute) are not same.  I think when you created the SVG, you (or your drawing tool) defined so.  If I create such animation,  I use "use" element to reuse path definition like this http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/OYvq